# In a Bash Script how does the continue command work with embedded loops?

Tags: bash, shell, control-flow

I am writing a bash script in a busybox session.

The script has to initiate an external executable numerous times in sequence in daemonised form then monitor the output.

```
while read LINE; do
  VARIABLEPARAMETER=`echo "$LINE" | sed -e 's/appropriateregex(s)//'`
  externalprog --daemonize -acton $VARIABLEPARAMETER -o /tmp/outputfile.txt
  until [ "TRIGGERED" = "1" ]; do
    WATCHOUTPUT=`tail -n30 /tmp/outputfile.txt`
    TRIGGERED=`echo "$WATCHOUTPUT" | grep "keyword(s)"` 
    if [ -z "$TRIGGERED" ]; then
      PROGID=`pgrep externalprog`
      kill -2 "$PROGID"
      continue
    fi
  done
done < /tmp/sourcedata.txt
```

My question is which of the two loops will the continue command be executed against?

The initial while read line, or the subsequent, until triggered?

Please don't get to focused on the actual code I've thrown this together as an example to try to explain this question, the actual code is much more detailed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From "help continue":

```
continue: continue [n]
    Resume for, while, or until loops.

    Resumes the next iteration of the enclosing FOR, WHILE or UNTIL loop.
    If N is specified, resumes the Nth enclosing loop.

    Exit Status:
    The exit status is 0 unless N is not greater than or equal to 1.
```

So you want `continue` or `continue 1` to go to the next iteration of `until`, or `continue 2` to go to the next iteration of `while`.